# Magento media folder permissions change after reindexing

Tags: php, magento, cron, server, webserver

I am having a problem with my Magento site.

I have 8 instances of my server and I use a cron job to index and cache management, currently I add a sub domain and add another project on server.

The problem is every time the re-indexing happens some media files and folders lose their permissions and then I have to assign 777 permissions to media folder.

I can't do that task every time because my site is live, I need a permanent solution for this.

I already assigned 777 permissions to media folder but still this is happening.

Please anyone can help me to look into the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use access list in order to achieve that.

```
HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX mediadirectory
sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX mediadirectory
```

With this you're giving access rwX to your httpd user in order to avoid your issue.
Hope this help.

Comment: please can you enplane me a little bit more about it, where i can find the file for it.

Comment: No code it pretty much clear i am just confused how to use it and where i should put it

Comment: Sorry, what os are you using?